# Does FileVault on macOS Monterey say it will use a recovery key, regardless of your choice, if you have an Apple ID 2FA recovery key?

Tags: recovery, filevault, two-factor-authentication

Running a MacBook Pro 14" (M1 Pro, 2021) running Monterey 12.6 (FileVault off), if I go into System Preferences > Security & Privacy > FileVault, it says that if I use FileVault I would need a recovery key or my login password to access my data:

[image: FileVault off]

When I choose the option to turn on FileVault, however, it displays a message saying that my iCloud account could be used to unlock my disk if I forget my password, and it gives me two options, one being to use my iCloud account to unlock my disk, and the other being to generate a recovery key and not use iCloud:

[image: FileVault dialog]

However, after I choose the option to allow iCloud to unlock my disk, it tells me a recovery key has been set, and it makes no mention at all of using iCloud to recover access:

[image: FileVault on]

And yet, that wasn't the option I selected.

I asked Apple Support about it, and at first they thought it had to do with messed up settings because I had previously used Migration Assistant from an old Mac running Sierra. Note that since then, I have done Erase All Content and Settings, but support thought a glitch from Migration Assistant might have persisted despite doing that.

Then, I mentioned that my Apple ID has Two Factor Authentication with a recovery key selected as an option to recover access to my account if I lose my password and other devices. The support representative then said that this is why it's saying a recovery key is set, because it is referring to the Apple ID recovery key.

However, this seems like pretty poor wording if that's the case. I would normally never need that recovery key, even if I forget my MacBook Pro password, if I know my iCloud login. But the message in FileVault implies that I wouldn't simply log in to iCloud to recover my password, but that on top of that I would need the recovery key. (In fact, on the face of it, the message implies that I wouldn't use iCloud at all.) The support representative suggested that since it doesn't know whether I would have other devices available, it assumes that I wouldn't have any other way of getting into the iCloud account.

But the message itself makes me worry that if I'm not sure that that is what it is referring to, or that it might actually come to me needing the some recovery key regardless of whether I have other authorized devices to authenticate the login, maybe I wouldn't know how to recover access in the right way if I forget my Mac's login. Or maybe the other suggestion was right that it was a carryover from some glitch from Migration Assistant and I have to go all the way to erasing the hard drive via Recovery and reinstalling the system fresh to remove that glitch. I certainly don't want to accidentally end up with a situation that FileVault thinks I need a recovery key, which I never got, and which is actually *not* my Apple ID's recovery key.

**So can anyone with an Apple ID 2FA recovery key on a Mac running Monterey check System Preferences to confirm that the messages I'm getting in FileVault are normal, or conversely that they are not normal?** And can anyone confirm whether if I were to forget my Mac login that I could still log in from iCloud and not need my Apple ID recovery key?

Comment: Your screenshot 1 says you will need login password or recovery key. Screenshot 2 asks you where you want to store the recovery key and offers 2 safe places: Either in iCloud or you save it yourself.  [I don't use iCloud, but store the recovery key in 1Password]. I believe what you are seeing is normal and will work as you expect. I hopee someone else who does use iCloud to store the recovery key can confirm.

Comment: @Gilby Are you saying that it is just communicating poorly, that a recovery key is involved in some sense but that I would never interface with it and that iCloud would handle it? Note that I do not use iCloud Keychain.

Comment: Yes, the recovery key is being stored in iCloud. iCloud Keychain or iCloud Drive are irrelevant here.  But I would like someone to who stores FileVault recovery key this way to confirm.  Read https://www.macworld.com/article/231249/how-to-find-your-filevault-recovery-key-in-macos.html - particularly the first paragraph after the screenshot.